# Swift class extends Objective C delegate

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am trying to extend Objective C class in my Swift class. This is where I got so far:

`SINMessageClientDelegate` is Objective C class. `ViewController` is written in Swift. I already have Bridging Header, so I can use Objective C object in my Swift class.

This is how my Swift code class definition looks like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SINMessageClientDelegate {
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Type "ViewController does not conform to protocol SINMessageClientDelegate"
```

This is how definition of SINMessageClientDelegate looks like:

```
@protocol SINMessageClientDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)messageClient:(id<SINMessageClient>)messageClient didReceiveIncomingMessage:(id<SINMessage>)message;

- (void)messageSent:(id<SINMessage>)message recipientId:(NSString *)recipientId;

- (void)messageDelivered:(id<SINMessageDeliveryInfo>)info;

- (void)messageFailed:(id<SINMessage>)message info:(id<SINMessageFailureInfo>)messageFailureInfo;
```

I tried to create these methods using Swift in `ViewController`:

```
// Tells the delegate that a message has been received.
func messageClient(id: SINMessageClient, didReceiveIncomingMessage:SINMessage)
{

}

// Tells the delegate that a message for a specific recipient has been sent by the local user.
func messageSent(id: SINMessage, recipientId: NSString)
{

}

// Tells the delegate that a message has been delivered (to a particular recipient).

func messageDelivered(id: SINMessageDeliveryInfo)
{

}

func messageFailed(id: SINMessage, info: SINMessageFailureInfo)
{

}
```

Can someone advice what is the proper way of doing this, since I am getting the same error after adding my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem in the way you pose your question is that you're using the wrong words. You are not "extending a class". You are *conforming to* (or *adopting*) a *protocol*.

The trouble, however, is that you are *not* adopting it (conforming to it), as the error message rightly tells you. The reason apparently is that you don't know how to read Objective-C. You'll need to learn to do that in order to proceed. For example, given this Objective-C declaration:

```
- (void)messageClient:(id<SINMessageClient>)messageClient 
    didReceiveIncomingMessage:(id<SINMessage>)message;
```

The Swift implementation will need to be:

```
func messageClient(SINMessageClient, 
    didReceiveIncomingMessage message: SINMessage) { /* ... */ }
```

Whereas what you have is not at all the same thing. You have this:

```
func messageClient(id: SINMessageClient, 
    didReceiveIncomingMessage:SINMessage) { /* ... */ }
```

That is not a match, so you are not implementing the required method, but rather some totally different method. That's legal, but it has nothing to do with the protocol you are supposed to be conforming to. And the same for the rest of your declarations.

Comment: It might help you to look at my book, where I teach you to read Objective-C method declarations: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_objective_c_methods